# Force Multicolumn headers to obey Page Margins like non multicolumn tables

Tags: multicolumn

Issue:

I want to generate a table like ( table #2 ) that has two child columns for one parent column, but I also want this table to obey page margins and not stick out from the rest of them. (the others on my page are like table #1 and don't require child headers.)  This disobedience of page margins happens with shorter and longer tables.

I get part of that with table #1.  Can anyone provide some expertise or direction?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}                                                   
\usepackage[letterpaper, inner=18mm, outer=18mm, top=8mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}                                               
\usepackage{graphicx}                                           
\let\svtikzpicture\tikzpicture
\def\tikzpicture{\noindent\svtikzpicture}                                           
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}  
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}}  
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{4cm}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}

\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!15}    

Obeys margin rules but doesn't quite give me the functionality of the multicolumn to span multiple columns..
I noticed this table also wraps it's column headers..

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Mxxxxxxxxxxxx }  

\rowcolor{black}

\multicolumn{ 13 }{l}{\tiny\textbf{ Non-Multicolumn Table }} \\       

    \rowcolor{black!60}
    
            \tiny
         &  \tiny Long Desc
         &  \tiny 
         &  \tiny Longer Desc
         &  \tiny 
         &  \tiny Even Longer Description
         &  \tiny Even Longer Description
         &  \tiny Normal
         &  \tiny 
         &  \tiny Short
         &  \tiny
         &  \tiny An Even Longer Description
         &  \tiny 
         \\
    
    \rowcolor{black!40}

            \tiny  
         &  \tiny  child data 1
         &  \tiny  child data 2
         &  \tiny  child data 1
         &  \tiny  child data 2
         &  \tiny  
         &  \tiny  
         &  \tiny  child data 1
         &  \tiny  child data 2
         &  \tiny  child data 1
         &  \tiny  child data 2
         &  \tiny  child data 1
         &  \tiny  child data 2
         \\

            \tiny  price
         &  \tiny  price
         &  \tiny  price
         &  \tiny  price
         &  \tiny  price
         &  \tiny  
         &  \tiny  
         &  \tiny  price
         &  \tiny  price
         &  \tiny  price
         &  \tiny  price
         &  \tiny  price
         &  \tiny  price
         \\
                                    
\end{tabularx}

Does not obey Margin rules but gives me the functionality for multiple column spanning
I noticed this table does not wrap it's headers, and forces the table to expand their length.  

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Mxxxxxxxxxxxx }  

\rowcolor{black}

\multicolumn{ 13 }{l}{\tiny\textbf{ Multicolumn Table }} \\       

    \rowcolor{black!60}
    
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny }
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tiny Long Desc }
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tiny Longer Desc }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny A description so very long that you probably didn't read it all }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Even Longer Description }
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tiny Normal }
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tiny Short }
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tiny An even longer description }
         \\
    
    \rowcolor{black!40}

             \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny  }
         &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny child data }
         &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny child data}
         &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny child data}
         &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny child data}
         &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny  }
         &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny  }
         &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny child data}
         &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny child data}
         &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny child data}
         &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny child data}
         &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny child data}
         &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny child data}
         \\     
         
     \rowcolor{white}
     
             \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Text  }
        \\
                                    
\end{tabularx}

\medskip

This uses multicolumn headers and regular body.  As you can see the multicolumn doesn't quite match up to the cell.

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Mxxxxxxxxxxxx }  

\rowcolor{black}

\multicolumn{ 13 }{l}{\tiny\textbf{ Multicolumn Table }} \\       

    \rowcolor{black!60}
    
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny }
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tiny Long Desc }
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tiny Longer Desc }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny A description so very long that you probably didn't read it all }
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\tiny Even Longer Description }
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tiny Normal }
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tiny Short }
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tiny An even longer description }
         \\
    
    \rowcolor{black!40}

            {\tiny  }
         & {\tiny child data }
         & {\tiny child data}
         & {\tiny child data}
         & {\tiny child data}
         & {\tiny  }
         & {\tiny  }
         & {\tiny child data}
         & {\tiny child data}
         & {\tiny child data}
         & {\tiny child data}
         & {\tiny child data}
         & {\tiny child data}
         \\     
         
     \rowcolor{white}
     
            {\tiny Text  }
        &  {\tiny Text  }
        &  {\tiny Text  }
        &  {\tiny Text  }
        &  {\tiny Text  }
        &  {\tiny Text  }
        &  {\tiny Text  }
        &  {\tiny Text  }
        &  {\tiny Text  }
        &  {\tiny Text  }
        &  {\tiny Text  }
        &  {\tiny Text  }
        &  {\tiny Text  }
        \\
                                    
\end{tabularx}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: not directly related but why are you specifying the font in every cell (and why use a low level font selection rather than say `\tiny` ?)

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont A description so very long that you probably didn't read it all }`  You are forcing this entry to use `c` so single line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Much of this is generated by a loop and then rendered on a remote PC.  I figured someone would mention it, it just doesn't seem like too big of a deal.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Also, you're saying that my telling multicolumn to align a different way I can cause it to wrap?

Comment: yes of course (or more simply not use multicolumn) The only effect of using `\multicolumn{1}` is to change the column type and you are changing it to `c` which is singe line centred entry. you could specify x or M instead which are centred parboxes allowing line breaking but that is the column type anyway.

Comment: it may not be a "big deal" but it is wrong. If you set the font outside the table then the line spacing would be suitable for the font size, as you just set it in a local group inside each cell the line spacing is for normalsize but you have tiny letters.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok thank you for helping me.  I went ahead and switched out the unnecessary font stuff with just tiny.  In my practical example ( its got different data ) this actually helps a lot because the \tiny drastically reduced the font size and the table.  So the specific table in question is not extended beyond the page anymore.  Though it still doesn't obey Page Margins.  As for not using multicolumn, I am down for that.  Though I need multicolumn headers for child data (data specifying data).  Is it possible to do that without multicolumn?  Also, I updated the example with a picture.

Comment: obviously if you want a heading to span more than one column you can use multicolum, but you should use a column type that allows line breaking or nest a tabular or parbox that does, using `c` is like using `\mbox` and unrelated to tabels if you use `\mbox{...}` and `...` is wider than the page, then it will stick off the page. It is not a matter of "obeying page margins" it is "obeying _you_"  and you are specifying single line entrires.

Comment: Looking back this is an issue with my colkumn definitions and what I was telling it to do. 
 To fix my specific issue I abandoned multicolumn for the body (kept it for the headers) and placed a tabularx `X` column on the first column to the left. and the rest of them lined up.